# Add margin to popupmenu button flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]
hidden menu

[image]
active menu

I need to add some spacing to the bottom of the object, however as i understood flutter didn't provide this functionality.

That is my popupmenu button code.

```
  Widget usersPopupMenuButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(builder: (context) {
      return PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder: (context) => userTagsList(tags),
        elevation: 2,
        offset: Offset(2, -100),
        // offset doesn't work, because it starts from the top of menu, not from the 
        // bottom. menu should be always rendered above chattextfield, however amount of items of menu        
        // are not fixed.
        onSelected: (UserTag val) {
          BlocProvider.of<ChatFieldBloc>(context)
              .add(ChatFieldAddUser(tag: val));
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

userTagList:

```
List<PopupMenuEntry<UserTag>> userTagsList(List<UserTag> tags) {
    return List.generate(
        tags.length,
        (index) => PopupMenuItem(
            value: tags[index],
            child: UserTile(
              tag: tags[index],
            )));
  }
```

Comment: Wrap `PopupMenuButton` around Container and give it a margin.

Comment: @TirthPatel It doesn't work becouse it adds margin to icon, instead it should add margin to menu(to active menu)

Comment: @TolegenAkilbekov did you find any solution ?